# Can a macro simplify trait impl?

Tags: rust

I want to simplify files and indention levels for implementing several Traits for a given struct. Is there a way I can do something like this?

```
struct Foo { /* ommitted */ }

impl(Default(Foo)) fn default() -> Self {
  /* do something */
}
```

Obviously, it is possible to write

```
impl Default for Foo {
  fn default() -> Self {
    /* do something */
  }
}
```

but the enclosing text provides no more value than the macro I hope exists. Although I am new to Rust, I am well aware of (and frequently use)

```
#[derive(Default)]
```

but I am looking for a way to simplify actually implementing many traits. I would consider the following clear as well, but AFAIK it is not legal Rust. Note that the following is similar to [rust-lang #1250](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1281):

```
impl Foo {
  type Index::Output = Bar;
  trait Default fn default() -> Self {
    // ...
  }
  trait Debug fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
    // ...
  }
  trait Display fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
    // ...
  }
  trait Index<usize> fn index(&self, (r, c): (usize, usize)) -> &Self::Index::Output {
    // ...
  }
  fn my_custom_thing() -> () {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is to create a dialect of Rust, just because you do not fancy the language syntax. [You are not the first to try think this way](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/mac.h)... but it is usually a bad idea, if only because nobody will want to read or use your code.

Comment: Way to make someone feel welcome and expand the community rodrigo.

Comment: I had no intention to be rude or anything, apologies if it sounded like that. When I started Rust, coming from C++, Java, Python... I also felt weird to have the implementation of a `struct` split among several `impl` blocks and traits. But that's just how the language is, there are good reasons for being that way, and you get used after a while. What you suggest, while being a nice macro exercise, it not very useful for writing real code, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for that. I add Ruby to that mix, so I'm used to all kinds of weird combinations :-) I don't mind things split into multiple blocks, but I think there are some times where it detracts from readability. I really like the #1250 suggestion because it would allow splitting the impl blocks into logical groups, such as Ord + Cmp things together or Idx + MutIdx together or whatever the author thought makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I tried something like this, I found that it was easier to just write out the `impl`s.

Thus, I would advise against it. But if you insist, you could start out with the following:

```
macro_rules! quick_impl {
    ($structname: ident, Default, $($t:tt)*) => {
          impl Default for $structname {
              fn default() -> Self {
                  Self {$($t)*}
              }
          }
    };
    ($structname: ident, Debug, $($field:ident),*) => {
        impl std::fmt::Debug for $structname {
            fn fmt(&self, f: &mut ::std::fmt::Formatter) -> ::std::fmt::Result {
                f.debug_struct(stringify!($tyname))
                $(
                    .field(stringify!($field), &self.$field)
                )*
                .finish()
            }
        }
    };
    // here be more implementations
}
```

Usable like this:

```
struct S {
    a: usize,
    b: bool,
    c: char,
}

quick_impl!(S, Default, a:1, b:true, c:'c');
quick_impl!(S, Debug, a, b, c);
```

This macro goes a step further in that you do not have to say `trait` or `fn` in the arguments (as this is clear anyway).

Comment: Thanks @phimuemue. That isn't quite what I was seeking, but your response inspired me to try some custom macro approaches. After playing around for a while, I came to the same conclusion you did: not worth it.

Edit: I'm going to leave the question open for a while to see if anybody knows a crate with macros that do this well. I found several that were vaguely similar but none that did what I described above. I guess my best hope is that someone actually implements rust-lang #1250.

Comment: @Horati Can you elaborate in which ways this approach differs from what you want? Because as far as I can see, the only missing piece is writing a macro that calls `quick_impl` automatically for all the parameters you specify - which should not be too hard.

Comment: Sure. The difference is that I was just looking for some syntactic sugar to reduce the visual burden on the reader; i.e.,
**quick_impl!(S, Default) { fn default() -> Self {
  S { a:1, b: true, c: 'c' }
}}**
So a macro taking a block that adds
**impl Default for S {
  <block>
}**
It isn't that I think Rust syntax is bad or that I want to macro-ize away all typing. In C/C++, I've seen code full of quick_impl macros which ultimately obfuscates the meaning. Though, quick_impl for Default and Debug exactly as you have written are probably okay.